# Can't open folder - Location is not available

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, permissions, ntfs

I performed copy of all folders and files from hard disk A to hard disk B,

I had one shared folder on HDD A, this folder was also copied.

I removed HDD A from computer (disk is broken) and let there only HDD B.

Now, when I want to open this folder, I've got error " Location is not available" (see picture 1).

When I wanted to display Security settings of this folder in File Explorer, I've got message "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed" (picture 2)

Can you help me, please?

How can I open this folder, please?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was the Folder of Drive A a USER folder on A?  If so, the permissions relating to USER A probably did not follow. Try taking Ownership of the Folder on Drive B.

Comment: @John, please, tell me how?

Comment: If this does not work, copy Folder A on Drive A to c:\temp\Folder A on Drive A. Then copy that to Drive B. That will work well.

Comment: I tried copy this folder to another disk, Error - Copy: Could not access 1 folder D:\Downloads :-(

Comment: Lots of errors. Copy Folder A to a new area on the same drive A  (say top level folder C:\Files.   Now copy C:\Files to Drive B .  Does this work?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the folder? It seems to me that you copied a symbolic link to A, rather than A itself, and now this symbolic link is pointing to a non-existent disk.

Comment: @John
I tried copy folder to another HDD, to another folder on the same HDD,
and still the same Error - Copy: Could not access 1 folder D:\Downloads

Comment: @harrymc
Yes, it is folder.

Comment: You didn't understand my question.

Comment: @harrymc
please, can you help me, how do I know if it's symbolic link?

Comment: @harrymc
I tried "dir /a" and  there is <DIR>          Downloads

Comment: Try [NTFSLinksView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html).

Comment: @harrymc 0 links found by NTFSLinksView

Comment: Get-ChildItem 'D:\Downloads\'
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'D:\Downloads\' because it does not exist.

Comment: "I tried copy folder to another HDD, to another folder on the same HDD, and still the same Error - Copy: Could not access 1 folder D:\Downloads"  Does your Drive have errors?  Run CHKDSK to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question Background:**

Cannot copy a folder from one drive to another.

**Suggestions Offered:**

Make sure of permissions.
Copy to a different location.
Copy to the same drive.

> I tried copy folder to another HDD, to another folder on the same HDD,
> and still the same Error - Copy: Could not access 1 folder
> D:\Downloads

**Solution:**

Does your Drive have errors?

Run CHKDSK to check for errors and verify the disk.

Note: If CHKDSK finds and corrects errors, use the Manufacturer's drive test app, check the disk and consider replacing it.

Comment: "Chkdsk D: /scan /F" fixed all. Thank you all very much